# My Cookies is not parsed in the request_header. WithCredentials is already set to true

Tags: express, next.js, header, cors

My request_headers doesn't have my cookies in it. I already have withCredentials set and my cors is set up properly( i think).
please help :)

I have a server on ip:port and development of client is in localhost.

Here is my Cors Option

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  credentials: true, //access-control-allow-credentials:true
  optionSuccessStatus: 200,
};
```

Here is my Function

```
//Check for Cookies
app.get("/check-cookies", cors(corsOptions), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.cookies);
  const token = req.cookies.authToken;
  if (!token) return res.status(401).json({ error: "Unauthorized" });
  try {
    const user = jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
    console.log("User:", user);
    return res.status(200).json({ user });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(403).json({ error: "Forbidden" });
  }
});
```

Upon logging in here is how i save the token

```
// Save token in a HttpOnly cookie
          res.cookie("authToken", token, {
            httpOnly: false,
            secure: false, // This should be set to true if you're using HTTPS
            sameSite: "lax",
            expires: new Date(Date.now() + 8 * 3600000), // cookie will be removed after 8 hours
          });
```

and here is my client getting that.

```
const handleTest = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        "http://ip:port/check-cookies",
        {
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      );
      console.log("Response:", response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
  };
```

I have also tried
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

Which also doesn't work.

please help me figure out what's wrong